# perl: function name clash

Tags: perl, module

Let's say, there are two modules is our framework: Handler.pm and Queries.pm

Queries.pm is optional and is being loaded at fastcgi process startup

```
BEGIN {
&{"check_module_$_"}        () foreach (Queries);

}

sub check_module_queries {
...
    require Eludia::Content::Queries;
...
}
```

every module function is loaded in one common namespace

now, there are two functions with same name (setup_page_content) in Handler.pm and Queries.pm

setup_page_content is being called in Handler.pm

It looks like original author suggested that Queries.pm:setup_page_content will be called, whenever Queries.pm is loaded

Sometimes it doesn't happen: traceback (obtained via caller ()) in these cases indicates, that setup_page_content was called from module Handler.pm

I logged %INC just before call and it contains Queries.pm and it full path in these cases

This behaviour is inconsistent and pops like in 2-3% of attempts on production installation, mostly when I send two parallel identical http requests. Due amount of effort to reproduce, I doesn't determine yet, whether it is installation specific.

**How it will be decided which version of function with same name  will be called?**

**Is it well-defined behaviour?**

There should be a reason, original author wrote the code this way

**UPDATE**

perl version is `v5.10.1 built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi`

**UPDATE 2**

code: [Handler.pm](https://github.com/do-/eludia/blob/master/Eludia/Content/Handler.pm) and [Queries.pm](https://github.com/do-/eludia/blob/master/Eludia/Content/Queries.pm)

Queries.pm loading occurs in check_module_queries (BEGIN {} of [Eludia.pm](https://github.com/do-/eludia/blob/master/Eludia.pm)),

loaded for every request using [Loader.pm](https://github.com/do-/eludia/blob/master/Eludia/Loader.pm) (via `use Loader.pm <params>`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are not proper modules. These are simply libraries. If you turn them into proper modules with proper name spacing you won't have this issue. You barely need to do anything more than:

package Queries;

sub new {

```
my $proto = shift;
my $class = ref($proto) || $proto;
my $self = {};

bless ( $self, $class );

return $self;
```

}

And you'll be well on your way. Of course your program will need a couple changes to actually access the class functions. You can look at exporting to the functions to possibly save some refactoring time.

I have forked the code at github and initiated a pull request that I hope will address your problem.

Comment: I just noticed this in Eulida.pm, "We totally neglect most of so called 'good style' conventions. We do find it really awkward and quite useless." That is your problem.

Answer (score 5):

> I'd like to call Custom.pm:setup_page_content, whenever Custom.pm is loaded

So you'd like to call `Custom::setup_page_content` when it exists.

```
if (exists(&Custom::setup_page_content)) {
   Custom::setup_page_content(...);
} else {
   Handler::setup_page_content(...);
}
```

---

> Sometimes it doesn't happen.

The total lack of information about this prevents me from commenting. Code? Anything?

---

> Is there a way to 'unload' a module but leave it in %INC?

Loading a module is simply running it. You can't "unrun" code. At best, you can manually undo some of the effects of running it. Whether that includes changing `%INC` or not is entirely up to you.

Comment: @jonny, Do you seriously expect to go through 1200 lines to find the one that decides which module to use?

Comment: no, that's why I didn't post the code in the first place and tried to tell, what's going on. In those cases defined (&Eludia::Content::Queries::setup_page_content) shows nothing, but main::setup_page_content do, I think, this means it was successfully imported to global namespace

Comment: @jonny, It case it wasn't clear, that was a request for you to point out the relevant code where this check is.

Comment: it is not a check but just a `require` call. As I wrote, it is called from BEGIN {} section of `Eludia.pm` (line 945): `&{"check_module_$_"}        () foreach sort grep {!/^_/} keys %{$conf -> {core_modules}};`. $conf -> {core_modules} contains Queries.pm in every bad case

Comment: sorry my English :D. What I mean, it stands there to run Queries.pm and load all it functions in global namespace. As far as I can understand, I can't use exists(&Eludia::Content::Queries::setup_page_content) check to decide, what version to call, since it does not exist and main::setup_page_content - trying to figure out why...

Comment: @jonny, You want to "call Custom.pm:setup_page_content, whenever Custom.pm is loaded". I showed you how. You also want to know why your current solution doesn't work. After two updates and three post, all I know about your solution is that it uses `require`. You're making it impossible to answer your question. Well maybe not. `require` doesn't do anything remotely related to what you want to do, so I'm guessing your solution doesn't work because you're using entirely wrong tools for the job.

Comment: it's not my solution. It works 97% of a cases. I have two options - Original author was dangerously wrong via introducing something with undefined behaviour (unfortunately he is inncaccessible now)  - Understand the mechanincs of clush name function call

Comment: Namespace conflicts aren't undefined behavior.  The last module to load prior to the function call will be the one who's function is in place when it's called.  Being that the global namespace is just a type of hash... consider what happens when you assign something to a hash element, and then assign something else to the same hash element.  The last thing assigned is what you find when you check the element.

Comment: @DavidO, please post your answer and point to something 'official'

Answer (score 4):

When there is a namespace collision, the most recently defined/loaded function will take precedence.

Comment: Where in the perl doc might this be explained / specified?

Comment: Weird, I can't find it in official perl documentation, but check this out -- http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl4/porm/ch02_06.htm.

Comment: I suspect it's not document like that because really all that's happening is you're redefining something; in this case, a function. And we should all have a pretty good understanding of how that works.

Comment: if it is just redefining, ok, `I GUARANTEE THAT` will do me :)

Comment: @Mike Samuel, There's no such thing as a namespace collision, so you won't find any documentation on it

Comment: @Mike Samuel, As for multiple assignments to a symbol table entry, like all assignments, the last value assigned is the one currently held.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour is perfectly defined: when you call PACKAGENAME::function_name, PACKAGENAME::function_name is called. It cannot be more than one PACKAGENAME::function_name at at time.

It is possible to redefine each function so many times as you wish. When you, say, execute some code like

```
eval "sub PACKAGENAME::function_name {...}";
```

the function is [re]defined. When you `require` some `.pm` file, it's much like `eval` the string with its content.

If PACKAGENAME is not defined explicitly, the `__PACKAGE__` value is used.

So if you remark that the version of `setup_page_content` is taken from `Handler.pm`, it must indicate that `Handler.pm`'s content was executed (by `use`, `require`, `read`/`eval` etc.) after `Queries.pm` was loaded (for the last time).

So you have to track all events of `Handler.pm` loading. The easy way is to add some debug print at the start of `Handler.pm`.